# Capture a value from a dropdownlist where the display dropdownlist is not default

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, dropdown

I want to capture the selected date on my `DropDown` list, where there are five days will display on `DropdownList`.

I'm usually putting the default value on `DropDown`, but not this time because in the drop down list I want it always display the current date and the next five days. But I don't know how to capture the data.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddldate" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        items.Add(new ListItem(
          DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString(), 
          DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString()));
    }
    ddldate.DataSource = items;
    ddldate.DataBind();
    ddldate.Items[0].Selected = true;
}
```

---

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string deliverytime = ddldate.SelectedValue.ToString();
    lbltest.Text = deliverytime;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're repopulating the `DropDownList` for every postback and reloading the page, hence the `SelectedValue` property value may be different from the posted value. Just put a check against `IsPostBack` to prevent repopulating `DropDownList` data on postback:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
           items.Add(new ListItem(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString()));
        }

        ddldate.DataSource = items;
        ddldate.DataBind();
        ddldate.Items[0].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should not bind data on `PostBack`, change your `FormLoad` code to below sample:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new ListItem(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString()));
        }
        ddldate.DataSource = items;
        ddldate.DataBind();
        ddldate.Items[0].Selected = true;
    }   
}
```

If you check the `PostBack` property as condition, your `SelectedValue` will keep, otherwise `DropDown` will bind on each page-post.

And I also recommend you to check `SelectedValue` status before use it, don't try to get value if this `null`, check the following code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ddldate.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        string deliverytime = ddldate.SelectedValue.ToString();
        lbltest.Text = deliverytime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean `PostaBack`?